# Best practices to reduce Azure consume in a web sites

Tags: azure

I have moved a classic ASP site with a SQL Database to Azure.
We moved from a shared hosting.

The sites runs really fast and we are happy with Azure.
Our only situation is the cost. We pass from a Us $8 monthly cost to a Us$ 90.
And we have only 8000 visits per month.

Actually the 90% of the cost of processor hours and 10% is BD units.

Is there some best practices we can use in Azure Websites so we can reduce this cost without changing the web (which is a very old one)?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be curious what you find. that was one of my biggest issues; they charge on a 60-minute billing cycle. So if someone hits your website at 6:01 (for one query), the entire hour is billed.

Comment: How are you hosting it on Azure?

Comment: I don´t understand the question @sabbour, How? Do you refer what we use? We have a website and a SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Azure is a real good alternative to replace $8/mo shared hosting.  Azure provides a more... sophisticated and scalable environment.  You're getting very impressive suite of middleware (cache, storage, nosql, relational, acs, vpn, etc) and managed environment, but the implication is that your either middleware, management or scalability needs are a little more demanding than $8/mo shared hosting can provide.

So in a nutshell, if you were happy with $8/mo - you should have probably stayed there.

Comment: Thanks Igorek.. But really we are very happy with Azure. Our site web app is fast... In the old shared hosting we had a very slow response.
My question is if there are options (like the ones you mentioned: cache, storage...) that we can config to optimize Azure resources.